# Why '12345'[::-1] does't start with index=0 , while '12345'[::1] starts with index =0 as usual?

Tags: python, indexing, slice

```
    a='12345'
    print(a[::1]) : index starts with 0
```

Output : 12345

```
    print(a[::-1])  : index starts with -1 ,
```

Output : 54321

Output should be 15432 , index must start as usual with 0

Comment: Because if a slice with a negative step started with index 0 by default, you wouldn't get anything.

Comment: No , we will get 154321 or should 15432

Comment: You are probably thinking that the behavior under the scenes for your negative slicing is `a[0:len(a)-1:-1]` but it will return an empty string. What is really happening behind is `a[len(a)-1:None:-1]` (end=None -> zero IS included; end=0 -> zero IS NOT included)

Comment: As your mention  a[len(a)-1:None:-1] , I agree this the gives the answer , I think this sclicing is folowing a reverse method as `__radd__` (not this method but its reverse way). and this agrees what I guess in my question , with negative step starting index it will not be 0 . Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Python's indexing operator works as follows:

`[start:end:step]`

I assume when you ask about starting with 0, you mean the first argument. It's true that to get the first character you would need to do

```
>>> string = "12345"
>>> string[0]
'1'
```

But what is being done here is that the step is being modified, because the first two arguments are left empty, so are assigned to default values. A step of 1 just means that each character will be selected in order, so nothing changes. A step of 2 would print every other character:

```
>>> string[::2]
'135'
```

and a step of -1 moves through the string backwards and prints it in reverse as you showed.

Comment: No , That not answer for my question .